# CSS mobile responsive div table wont float next to each other

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm totally mindblocked and need YOUR help! Can anyone explain me why those div wont float next to each other?

```
        <div class="table">
        <div class="row1">
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableDayA">Datum - Tag</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">BL</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">2. BL</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">Pokal</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">UCL</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">UEL</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">FIFA</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">A-Länderspiele</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">U21-Länderspiele</div>
            <div class="tableCellHead" id="tableHead">Sonstiges</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row2">
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableDay">Montag, 07.10.2013</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableContent1">lorem</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row3">
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableDay">Dienstag, 08.10.2013</div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row4">
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableDay">Mittwoch, 09.10.2013</div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row5">
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableDay">Donnerstag, 10.10.2013</div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row6">
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableDay">Freitag, 11.10.2013</div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row7">
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableDay">Samstag, 12.10.2013</div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
        </div>
            <div class="row8">
            <div class="tableCell" id="tableDay">Sonntag, 13.10.2013</div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
            <div class="tableCell"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
body {

}
div#tableDayA {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

div#tableHead {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
    background: green;
    width: 49%;
    display: block;
}

div#tableContent1 {
    clear: right;
    margin: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
    float: right;
    background: pink;
    width: 49%;
    display: block;
}

div#tableDay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}
}
```

and this looks like this. the goal is to make those divs float next to each other.

http://postimg.org/image/58j541f63/

really apprieciate the help.

Comment: Look at what you are naming your classes...Shouldn't you be using a `<table>` instead?

Comment: IDs have to be _unique_ within an HTML document.

Comment: thats the point, i have to make tablets based on divs. and btw CBroe the problem is i cant modify the html. do you think the problem lies exactly in IDs?

Comment: Are you sure? Tables are perfectly acceptable for tabular data--which is what you appear to need them for.

Comment: the trick was to make them transform to look completly different on mobile. table doesnt allow that without javaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent divs are block level elements. You've got to change them to inline-block elements. Give them a width, something like 33% each. And float them left. More specifically:

```
div.row1, div.row2, div.row3, ... {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 33%; // or whatever
}
```

And your div.table needs to be 100% wide since it's the parent container:

```
div.table {
width: 100%;
}
```

And use media queries to alter the div.ro1, div.row2, etc. widths to 100% at smaller screen sizes so they stack.